# Mapping locale.json messages to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I've been dealing with i18n and locales and in i.e vue theres a function `t()` that takes one parameter - string that represents a path(name of a key) in .json file to a string that's expected to be shown in app

```
//en.json
{
  "about": "About"
}
```

then in template/html you would do something like `t("about")` and I was wondering if you could create a function that will read such `en.json` and make it into an object where key would be the .json key and value would be the key but of string. this way you could then expose it somewhere as global or something I haven't thought it through and instead of `t("about")` you'd do `t($locale.about)` in your templates (I'm looking to erase the need of hardcoded strings in the codebase)

It's just a thought and I'm wondering if its possible and something that actually should be done or not?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't like this by design. Translation keys are allowed to be missing and a fallback can be supplied to the second parameter of `t()`. This is important when you have multiple catalogues for different languages, and some keys may not have translations in certain catalogues. This also allows the internationalisation lib to then fall back to another locale if preferred, as per the library configuration.

Otherwise, what would be the point of the intl library? It's functionality would be reduced (albeit, not eliminated, since I guess `t()` still gives you interpolation and other things like dates etc). You could just have a JSON file with all the messages and import it directly without any `t()` calls if you don't care about the intl library's flexibility and behaviours.

That said it's still good to be able to detect missing messages or unused keys etc. That problem is usually solved by other tooling in the build process. See [vue-cli-plugin-i18n](https://github.com/intlify/vue-cli-plugin-i18n).

Comment: Im not sure if you misunderstand me or I phrased my question wrongly, I understand the strength of the library, but take that t function. You feed it a string that represents a key value in a json file and from that you can get the appropriate value to show on the screen

Comment: and my point is, that I dont want to have to do t(hardcodedstring) but rather t(object.attribute) to ensure type safety when acccessing the locale messages, and I wanted to achieve it by reading the file before build or something and map the keys onto an object where a name of an attribute would simply be the same key as is in the json file and value of that attribute would be the name of the attribute but of string type, this way you have type safety and also easier time looking for appropriate message